# How to actually store an onclick function in localstore so it doesn't refresh all back to default

Tags: javascript, onclick, local-storage

I want to change the currency of an existing products' prices that are in JOD (1 JOD = 1.41$ )
I did that using convertToUSD() function in Js, however, I couldn't save the changes, whenever I refresh the page the old price with the old currency is set back to the default price.

How could I save the changes?

HTML:

```
<section class="section center products_available" id="products_available">
    <div class="all_products center" id="all_products">
        <!-- first product -->
        <div class="product_item" id="skirt" name="Tutu Skirt">
            <div class="product_description">
                <!-- img, name -->
                <img src="./assets/images/tutu-skirt1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="p_text">
                    <!-- shows on hover -->
                    <h2 class="add-to-cart" onclick="addToCart()">Add to cart</h2>
                    <h1>Tutu skirt</h1>
                    <h4></h4>
                    <div class="price_fav_ivon">
                        <!-- add to wishlist -->
                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined favorite_icon">
                            favorite
                        </span>
                        <p id="price">5</p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- colors available -->
                    <div class="p_colors_available">
                        <input type="radio" value="#" class="color_available">
                        <input type="radio" value="#" class="color_available">
                        <input type="radio" value="#" class="color_available">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id="btn">Change</button>
        <style>
            #btn {
                position: relative;
                cursor: pointer;
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- other product -->
        <div class="product_item">
            <div class="product_description">
                <!--  img, name, price -->
                <img src="./assets/images/tutu-skirt2.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="p_text">
                    <!--  shows on hover -->
                    <h2 onclick="addToCart()">Add to cart</h2>
                    <h1>Tutu skirt</h1>
                    <h4></h4>
                    <div class="price_fav_ivon">
                        <!-- add to wishlist -->
                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined favorite_icon">
                            favorite
                        </span>
                        <p id="price">5</p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- colors available -->
                    <div class="p_colors_available">
                        <input type="radio" value="" class="color_available">
                        <input type="radio" value="" class="color_available">
                        <input type="radio" value="" class="color_available">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Js:

```
//adding JOD to indicate the current currency
let prices = document.querySelectorAll('#price');
prices.forEach((price) => {
    price.textContent += " JOD";
});
 
let toggleCurrencyBtn = document.getElementById("btn")
 
//to change the currency
btn.addEventListener('click', convertToUSD);
 
function convertToUSD() {
    prices.forEach((price) => {
        let priceText = price.textContent;
        let priceValue = parseFloat(priceText);
        let usdPrice = priceValue * 1.41;
        price.textContent = usdPrice.toFixed(2) + " USD";
 
        //Save the new price in local storage
        localStorage.setItem("prices", usdPrice.toFixed(2) + " USD")
    });
}
```

I tried the:

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

But I couldn't understand it so it didn't seem to work. Here are my codes:

Comment: Please repost your code. Put it in a code block, not a quotation block. This is the `{}` tool instead of `''`

Comment: Use [code fences](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format your code. [Test formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) before posting questions.

Comment: you can't store a function in local storage. It can only store strings.

Comment: I see where you're *setting* data in `localStorage`, but where are you *getting* data from `localStorage`?  Did you just forget to add that logic when loading the page?

Comment: You can't store functions in localStorage, only strings
my advice is to save the current currency used in localStorage and read it each time the webpage loads
then do the appropriate conversion with the chosen currency

Answer (score -1):

These are the steps you can follow:

1. Load the converted prices from local storage when the page loads.
2. Update the prices with the converted values.
3. Store the updated prices back in local storage whenever the conversion is performed.

Here is the modified code:

```
// Function to convert prices to USD
function convertToUSD() {
    prices.forEach((price, index) => {
        let priceText = price.textContent;
        let priceValue = parseFloat(priceText);
        let usdPrice = priceValue * 1.41;
        price.textContent = usdPrice.toFixed(2) + " USD";

        // Save the new price in local storage
        localStorage.setItem("price_" + index, usdPrice.toFixed(2) + " USD");
    });
}

// Function to load converted prices from local storage
function loadConvertedPrices() {
    prices.forEach((price, index) => {
        const convertedPrice = localStorage.getItem("price_" + index);
        if (convertedPrice) {
            price.textContent = convertedPrice;
        }
    });
}

// Event listener for the currency toggle button
toggleCurrencyBtn.addEventListener('click', convertToUSD);

// Load converted prices when the page loads
window.addEventListener('load', loadConvertedPrices);
```